# alphabet "a" in latex

Tags: beamer, math-fonts

How to write alphabet "a" in latex?

I am writing equations
[image]

but I want "a" to look like this?

[image]

Comment: it's just an a.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  But I am not getting it...

Comment: well there are millions of fonts, I can't guess exactly which one is used in your image and every font will look slightly different but does it matter, it's just an a, do you also need the square full stop not a round  one?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I just need the "a" ...haha

Comment: so you have added an image which makes it clear you have selected a non standard math font,  so the answer is, in code you have not shown do not do whatever you did, so you get the default. It is hard to tell people how to change unseen code

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz yes it does..thanks

Comment: @Jonathan In the future, please always include a small, but compilable test file in your questions. This way we don't have to guess the class you use based on the colour of your bullet points ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, beamer uses a sans serif font for math. If you prefer serif font, you can use `\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\[
a^n
\]

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]